# Could not get google-services-4.3.3 - Firebase implementation

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, build.gradle

I'm new in Android Studio and I'm trying to implement Firebase in my project but an error occured while I'm trying to implement **"classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'"**.

I get this error : **Could not GET google-services-4.3.2, 403 Forbidden** when I'm trying to sync Gradle.

Here is my project/build.gradle :

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app/build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxxxxx.tabataworkout"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    def room_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: check your network connection

Comment: Check your network connection is not stable

Comment: Also might be worth upgrading your gradle version in your project/build.gradle from 3.1.1 to something like 3.5.2